# Adding north arrow using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, north-arrow

I am trying to put the north arrow on the graphic output of the map using PyQGIS (QGIS 3.4). I tried adding it as an image with the attached code but I have the background of the image and it does not fit. Would there be any other way?

```
north = QgsLayoutItemPicture(layout)
north.setPicturePath("C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/logo.png")
layout.addLayoutItem(north)
north.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(23, 23,gsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
north.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(3,234,QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a .png image, use a **.svg** file with a **transparent background**.

```
north = QgsLayoutItemPicture(layout)
north.setPicturePath("C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/logo.svg")
layout.addLayoutItem(north)
north.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(23, 23,gsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
north.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(3,234,QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
```